How to tell Linux it's running on batteries?
Whenever I inspect the current state of my Raspberry via the htop command, it shows the battery information is not available.

Is there any way to tell my Linux (Ubunutu 22.0.4 LTS) about the current state of the battery it is running on?

htop expects to find battery information in /proc/acpi/battery. This only works on ACPI-compliant systems, which doesn’t include Raspberry Pis (or any other ARM-based SBCs as far as I’m aware). So short of modifying htop itself, you won’t be able to change its output.
The Linux kernel itself might know about your battery; if it’s described in your platform device tree, it should show up somewhere under /sys/firmware/devicetree. If the power controller is supported, it will show up under /sys/bus/platform/devices; for example, my battery-equipped Pine A64+ has an axp20x-battery-power-supply directory there. This allows tools such as sensors to discover the battery:
$ sensors
axp20x_battery-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:           4.14 V
curr1:       1000.00 uA

